# Placing executable file in git project for Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, packaging, launchpad

I have a [Launchpad project](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge) that I have a git repository for. The executable is a shell script. I have placed the script in usr/bin in git currently. But does it matter in which directory it is placed in? Maybe I should have placed it in the root directory of the software directory. Can one move a file in git afterwards to different directory?

Answer (score 1):

> Can one move a file in git afterwards to different directory?

Yes, as long as it's still within the repository. In other words, for the file to still be tracked by Git, it needs to be a child of the directory which contains the `.git` directory.

Perhaps a good solution for your use-case would be to use a symbolic link to wherever you store your shell script so it's actual location can remain in place within your repository.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the file to the base directory by `git mv`. The target install directory of the package can told in install file(s), see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/202298/21005) for more specific information.